# How to bind publish port in Dockerfile on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, port, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I try to deploy asp.net docker on aws

This is my Dockerfile (from microsoft docker example)

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["kpm", "restore"]

EXPOSE 80:80
ENTRYPOINT ["k", "kestrel"]
```

The problem is. I can use commandline to call [ docker run -p 80:80 image ] to run docker properly

But when I use AWS Beanstalk to deploy my dockerfile. It cannot map public port to docker port automatically. I need to run docker run -p again to make it usable

[image: Image here is my command from putty]

At start there are image that's work and container that run. But it seem it can't map port so it die. I then need to run a run command with -p again to make it work

I have no clues how aws will run docker with -p on which port. please help me

Comment: Can you check Docker logs (just use "docker logs CONTAINER_ID")? It looks like it stops right away for some reason.

Comment: logs command only print "started" and that's all

Comment: @sap1ens And rights, It stop right after it start. The only difference from work and not work is only it has port bind when I run with -p manually